# junit jupiter run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm learn java, and now i have a mistake: cannot find class 'org.junit.platform.commons.annotation.testable' on project build path
I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. in other projects junit work successful [image: my settings]
My project explorer [ProjectExplorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37c6Q.png)
I'm tryed to add junit in build path, change test runner to Junit4 and add other version of Junit in dependency, but it did not working to me.

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <exec.version>3.0.0</exec.version>
  <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
  <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
  <junit.version>5.7.0</junit.version>
  <junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>1.3.2</junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>
<!-- some other things -->
 
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${exec.version}</version>
  </dependency>  <!-- Test dependency -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${junit-platform-surefire-provider.version}</version>
  </dependency>
<!-- some other dependency -->
  
 <!-- Logger dependency -->
 
  <!-- Services dependency -->
  
</dependencies>
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>/src/main/java </sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>/src/test/java </testSourceDirectory>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
          <includes>
            <include>**\testWindowLogin.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform-surefire-provider.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${exec.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you share a picture of your project structure? Usually you get this error when your tests are located inside your sources (src/main/java) instead of your tests (src/test/java).

Comment: I add picture of my project explorer in start message of topic

Comment: Remove the dependency to the `junit-platform-surefire-provider` furthrmore remove the dependency to `junit-platform-surefire-provider` in the plugin configuration for maven-surefire-plugin as well. Furthrmore remove the include configuration and follow the default naming schema either `TestWindowLogin.java` or `WindowLoginTest.java`...  remove also the configuration entries for `<sourceDirectory>..` as well as `<testSourceDirectory>..`...

Comment: Remove the whole project from your Eclipse configuration and reimport the whole project via import function of Eclipse as Maven Project....

Comment: @CapitanNemo Did you try to run Maven on the command line, e.g. `mvn clean install`?

Comment: @funfried I tried, but it didn't work for me. Actually, several minutes I solve this problem, but i still cannot belive that I did it. I have to check

Answer (score 0):

so. i can say that i fix it.
first: my IDE -- Eclipse version 4.19; Maven version 3.6.3, java version 11.0.10
second. simple import project from git didn't work in. For fix I import to local repository and then did import to IDE as maven project.

thanks for help